# SQL extracting data from SQL column

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, t-sql

I have SQL table JSON data into one of the columns. The column type is varchar max.
  I have to extract the data from that column using sql.   For example

```
{"RESPONSE":{"value":"<p>this is a test.....</p>","isAnswered":true}}'
```

I want to extract: `this is a test.....`
and get rid of all attributes and Nodes
I am very new to JSON. Fisrt time looking into it and lost

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using TSQL

Comment: Hi, is that the full definition of the JSON string?

Comment: @YanireRomero  --- There different definations here are few examples  '{"RESPONSE":{"value":"<p>&nbsp;</p><p>This is a test.</p>","isAnswered":true}}'                                                              {"RESPONSE":{"value":["d"],"isAnswered":true},"RESPONSE1":{"value":["c"],"isAnswered":true}}                                                      {"RESPONSE1":{"value":["a"],"isAnswered":true}}

Comment: @YanireRomero-- Thanks a bunch. One quick question. Can I use a wild cardcharacter. For example. Response can be response1, Response 2 and response3 etc... So to exclude that should i use wild card character

Comment: @YanireRomero--   Thank you so much for providing solution. It was very helpful. I was just wondering instead of hardcoding the html tags in function is their namespace that we can use?

Comment: @TD2013 you would have to verify that the REPLACE is working according to that since it replaces exact match for string pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
begin transaction

declare @string varchar(max)
declare @result varchar(max)
declare @response varchar(max)

set @string = '{"RESPONSE":{"value":["d"],"isAnswered":true}}'

set @response = SUBSTRING(@string, PATINDEX('%response%',@string), PATINDEX('%":{"value"%',@string) - PATINDEX('%response%',@string))

print @response
-- for html tags

DECLARE @htmlTags TABLE 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
    htmlTag varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO @htmlTags
VALUES 
    ('<p>'),
    ('</p>'),
    ('<h1>'),
    ('</h1>'),
    ('"'),
    ('{'),
    ('}'),
    (':'),
    (','),
    ('value'),
    ('isAnswered'),
    ('true'),
    ('false'),
    ('&nbsp;'),
    ('['),
    (']')
;

SET @result = @string

DECLARE @temp varchar(max) = '';
WHILE @result != @temp
BEGIN
    SET @temp = @result;

    SELECT
        @result = Replace(@result, htmlTag, '')
    FROM
        @htmlTags
    ;
END;

set @result = REPLACE(@result, @response, '')

print @result

rollback
```

I'm assuming that the structure of your JSON response is:

{"RESPONSE":{"value":"","isAnswered":true}}

EDIT: I recommend to insert all html tags and names (like  ) into the htmlTags table to obtain the result you want since you cannot predict which one of them is going to appear in the json.

UPDATE: use this set @response = SUBSTRING(@string, PATINDEX('%response%',@string), PATINDEX('%":{"value"%',@string) - PATINDEX('%response%',@string)) so you can replace any kind of RESPONSE pattern in your json.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @TD2013 I tested multiple times, yes you have to use a wildcard and patindex to actually obtain the correct "RESPONSE" string and then replace it into the result. I updated my answer in order to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing solution. It was very helpful. Can you